# View method default behavior for overriding

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding, superclass

I'm learning how to use @override and its pretty awesome, right now I'm trying to find out how to view the methods you override. The API (I'm still new, so I may be wrong here) will tell you the method names and describe them but doesn't actually show you the code.

I use Eclipse's context assist to find the methods I can override, and I know I can call `super.'thismethod'()` to perform the default action, but what if I want to change something or just see if I really need to?

**Question:** How do I view the full method code of a superclass, for overriding purposes?

Thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the method and press F3 key that will take you to the super class implementation (Important you should have the code of Superclass in your classpath not just the class file)

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this is to run your application and turn on debugging, put breakpoints around the class you want to inspect, and then step into it. Some IDEs offer the ability to click into the source via a context sensitive menu, but I am not sure if Eclipse does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either select any method name and hit F3 to go to any method, so you would select (or just put the cursor on) the super.method() and hit F3. This would take you to the super method.

Better, select (or just put the cursor on) a method, and hit ctrl-T to see the type hierarchy, in which you can click the class you want to examine, and it will take you to the appropriate method.